# How to add Final Cartridge III to VICE C64/128 Emulator

Tags: commodore-64, emulation, game-cartridge, commodore-128

How do I properly add Final Cartridge III to VICE Emulator?
In the file menu, VICE has an item `Attach cartridge image...` which splits up into `CRT Image` but also a list of several cartridges, among them `Freezer Cartridges` -> `The final Cartridge III Image`. However, VICE is expecting a raw cartridge image file at that point.
I found a `.crt` file for Final Cartridge III on [csdb](https://csdb.dk/release/?id=141638) which I could start by attaching it as generic CRT cartridge, but I assume installing via the predefined way might provide better integration?

Further issue, is there a way to have the cartridge always enabled when I start VICE? Like the same way one would have this done at a computer in order to enjoy the comfort functions like fastloader and directory listing?

Finally, when running the Final Cartridge III via the crt file, the mouse emulation does not work, that is the pointer does not move although the catch mouse events option at VICE was enabled.

Comment: VICE can save settings in configuration files as well as accept them on the command line, so you could simply save the settings using the menu item to do that, enable automatically saving settings on exit, or, if you use multiple configurations, save the settings to a configuraiton file specific to that particular configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found a .crt file for Final Cartridge III on csdb which I could start by attaching it as generic CRT cartridge, but I assume installing via the predefined way might provide better integration?

The difference is only with a "raw" image, vice has to know the layout of it. If you have a `.crt` file, generic should be ok. See also http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/vice_7.html#SEC109

> Further issue, is there a way to have the cartridge always enabled when I start VICE?

You could use a script / batch file starting vice with the appropriate commandline options. (`-cartcrt /path/to/your.crt`)

> Finally, when running the Final Cartridge III via the crt file, the mouse emulation does not work, that is the pointer does not move although the catch mouse events option at VICE was enabled.

- You also need to enable a mouse emulation, just catching mouse events isn't enough. For example, to emulate the 1351 mouse, use `-controlport1device 3`, see also http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/vice_6.html#SEC59
- If you enable the mouse emulation later in the settings menu, it won't work with this cartridge until you reset, see this hint: http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/vice_7.html#SEC117